# How do I use the class AesManaged in a wp8 app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use the class `AesManaged` in my WP8 app, but I cannot find it in no namespace. It says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that the class should be availabe in version 4.5 of the .Net Framework.

Hence, I searched the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework for the namespace `System.Security`. I could only find it in .NetFramework\v4.0. However, apparently the namespace does not contain the class `AesManaged`. The folder \WindowsPhoneApp does not even contain the file System.Security.dll...

Is it possible to use the class in a wp8 app or are there other encryption libraries like bouncycastle available for WindowsPhone 8?

Comment: Yes, `AesManaged` is available on Windows Phone 8.  The online documentation details that it is contained within System.Core.dll.   Are using referencing the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace?  see also http://robtiffany.com/dont-forget-to-encrypt-your-windows-phone-7-data/

Comment: Yes, I added `using System.Security.Cryptography;`, but VS tells me that the namespace `Cryptography` is not contained in `System.Security` and whether I am missing an assembly reference. However, I do not know where I can find the appropriate assembly... `System.Core` is included by default.

Comment: Is this a Universal App or a Silverlight app?

Comment: I had a universal app first, but I also tried it in a WindowsPhone app now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already used it in a Windows Phone 8 app. Here it is :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aesmanaged(v=vs.105).aspx

> Version Information
>   Windows Phone OS
>   Supported in: 8.1, 8.0, 7.1, 7.0

I don't believe it exists in 8.1 WinRT however.

Comment: `System.Core` is listed in the object catalogue, but it does not contain the namespace `System.Security.Cryptography`. I created an empty WindowsPhone app, so the namespace should be there, shouldn't it?

Comment: Just to be sure, is it Windows Phone 8 or Windows Phone 8.1 RT (Universal app) ?
But yes it should definitely be there.

Comment: I am using MS VS Express 2013 and on creating the project, I selected Visual C# > Store-Apps > Windows Phone-Apps > Empty App (Windows Phone), the target platform is displayed as Windows Phone 8.1. I guess that's a Windows Phone 8 app, not Windows Phone 8.1 RT?
Also, `System.Core` is listed twice in the object catalogue: versions 2.0.5.0 and 4.0.0.0. Version 4.0.0.0 does not contain anything. Is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: It says (Windows Phone) for Windows Phone RT apps (aka Universal App), and Windows Phone Silverlight non RT apps.
So you are creating an RT app, that is why you cannot find AesManaged, because it doesn't exists in WinRT.
You have to use the WinRT APIs. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.encrypt.aspx

Comment: I am using the german version of VS, so I was a bit confused. Actually, I have three options: Universal app, Windows Phone app (which I thought was the non RT app...) and Windows Phone Silverlight, which I spotted now (and it works) :)